# Numerical approach of integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

If I have a equation
$$\int_0^{t} \int_{s(\tau)}^D f(x, \tau) d x d \tau=0$$
and I want to solve $s(t)$ for any given $t$. Here $D$ is a constant and $f(x,\tau)$ is a known function, is there a numerical method for solving $s(t)$? I was thinking a method like Runge–Kutta method for ODE, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean or provide some context? Do you want to find a function $s:[0,t]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that solves this integral equation? What properties should $s$ have? You could pick $s\equiv D$, but this is most probably not what your question is about.